# Apenas voy empezando programación estoy calculando un sueldo de un trabajador pero me suelta el sig error a la hora de sacar la operación

Tags: c++

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me aparece el sig. error que la expresión no puede ser usada como función

Comment: Lectura sugerida. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Esperamos a la edición de la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Es probable que el error se deba a qué tienes dos paréntesis juntos: `(...)(...)`. Supongo que te habrás olvidado escribir un + o un * entre ambos.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien no me equivoco al ser sueldo base este se divide entre 30 dias y se multiplican con el valor agregado en `diasextras` por lo cual la operación que tienes tendria un cambio al siguiente:

```
 diasextras = diasextras*(sueldoBase/30);

operacion = (diasextras + sueldoBase)-((sueldoBase*isr)+(sueldoBase*seguros));
```

Esto debido a los dias extras mas el sueldo junto con la resta del `seguros` e `isr`, si no es eso lo que buscabas entonces lo que comento Mateo es correcto, asegurarse de la suma, al final el codigo quedaria de esta forma:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int diasextras, operacion, total;
float sueldoBase = 3000, isr = 0.10, seguros = 0.15;

std::cout << "Cuantos dias extras realizaste?\n" << std::endl;

std::cin >> diasextras;
diasextras = diasextras*(sueldoBase/30);
operacion = (diasextras + sueldoBase) - ((sueldoBase*isr) + 
(sueldoBase*seguros));

cout << "Su sueldo total es de: "<<operacion<<". \n";
return 0;
}
```

Espero sea lo que buscas!!